# The target page changes its URL without a browser page load. How do I get my userscript to fire ONLY on a select page for this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

How can I specify in my Tampermonkey userscript for it only run on the home page of  Twitch `https://www.twitch.tv` as intended?

To elaborate:

- If I initially open `https://www.twitch.tv` then all subsequent Twitch channel pages I navigate to via clicking on the website, all run the script. (bad)
- Similarly, if I initially open
  `https://www.twitch.tv/NameOfSomeChannel` then all the subsequent
  Twitch pages I navigate to (including the home page) all do **not**
  run the script. (also bad)

Twitch pages are somehow fixed and all the new content on a different page is loaded on the same page if I navigate via clicking within the website (I don't know the technical term for this).

**How can I get around this issue so that only `https://www.twitch.tv` runs the script regardless of which webpage I initially opened?**

Below is my userscript. The purpose of it is to block the auto-play of the featured video on Twitch's home page.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Twitch Homepage Auto-Play Disable
// @version      0.1
// @description  Disables Twitch homepage featured video auto-play.
// @author       G
// @match        https://www.twitch.tv/
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("div.pl-overlay--loading", pausevideo);

function pausevideo () {

        if(!document.querySelector("#icon_play")){
            console.log("pausingvideo");
            document.querySelector('.qa-pause-play-button').click();
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I gave that a try and it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure it's matching more than it should?  Because according to the tampermonkey doc on @match, @match operates the same as @include, and according to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns , @include doesn't wildcard match the url unless you use the `*` character some how.

Comment: That's really strange. I tried reading up on it earlier, but I honestly have no clue, all I can say is that it honestly runs on every twitch.tv page as if I had put `https://www.twitch.tv/*`

Comment: twitch.tv/ resolves to some page.  an index.html or index.php or something.  If you can figure out what that page is, you could change your @match to be that exact path, and see if it stops multi page matching for you

Comment: Other than that, not sure.  You might try playing around with an @exclude and see if you can exclude anything that is not simply www.twitch.tv

Comment: My apologies, I'm really not familiar with this area, and I have no idea where to look. I can see `https://static.twitchcdn.net` from Chrome developer console as where Twitch gets a lot of its stuff (I don't even know the technical name for this), but I don't think that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I did try adding after `@match` `// @exclude https://www.twitch.tv/*` previously, but that simply resulted in the script not running at all.

Comment: I've tried removing `/` as well.

Comment: Would it be plausible to specify the home page specifically from within the script itself?

Comment: I mean that's what your doing with the @match, but for some reason it's wildcarding more than that, without you using the `*` which seems to be contrary to the docs.  But yeah, you could check the `window.location.href` for a specific value in an if statement

Comment: Sure.  `if (window.location.href !== 'https://www.twitch.tv/') { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: I've updated the script to `if (window.location.href === 'https://www.twitch.tv/') {

waitForKeyElements ("div.pl-overlay--loading", pausevideo);

function pausevideo () {

        if(!document.querySelector("#icon_play")){
            console.log("pausingvideo");
            document.querySelector('.qa-pause-play-button').click();
        }

}

}` It still runs on every twitch.tv page. And for some reason `!==` makes the script not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help though, I really do appreciate it. I feel like I've kind of hit a dead end.

Comment: Yeah, we need someone else more familiar with the @match to chime in, heh.

Comment: Alright, I have a substantial lead that I didn't expect. This applies both with the `if (window.location.href` and without it (so it's effectively useless). But basically @match is fine. If I cleanly open the page `https://www.twitch.tv` first, then all subsequent pages of Twitch channels I move on to automatically have their videos paused. And similarly, if I initially open a specific Twitch channel's page first, the script does not run, and all subsequent pages I navigate to from there including the Twitch homepage all do not run the script. Do you have any idea how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site "changes" pages via ajax-load<sup>‡</sup>, so that means that **your script must run on all pages** because the home page can be "loaded" without an HTML `GET`. (Tampermonkey only fires once per standard `GET`.)

Then, in your pause function, check to see if the home page has been ajaxed into the tab. Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Twitch Homepage Auto-Play Disable
// @match        https://www.twitch.tv/*
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces */

waitForKeyElements ("div.pl-overlay--loading", pauseVideo);

function pauseVideo () {
    if (location.href === "https://www.twitch.tv/"  &&  !document.querySelector("#icon_play") ) {
        console.log ("===> Pausing video.");
        document.querySelector('.qa-pause-play-button').click ();
    }
}
```

**Important:**  This script, based on the OP's code, will also stop the user from manually playing videos on the home page <sup>(A good thing, IMO, see the footnote)</sup>.
So, if you want to be able to click "play" on those videos, you will need more sophisticated logic.  That is out of scope for this question, ask a new question for that, if needed.

---

<sup>‡</sup> And it's also extraordinarily "busy" and annoying.  Perhaps a better userscript would be:

```
alert("This site saps your life and IQ.  Close the tab and go for a walk (optional dog, recommended).")
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked flawlessly. I was aware that the script would not allow the user to play videos on the home page, as my intention from the start was to use the script in conjunction with adblocking that entire div (the issue with only using Adblock is that it only hides the div cosmetically, you can still hear the auto-play audio).